# Select files by extension using grep

Tags: linux, grep

I need to count all the .txt files in the current folder.
I tried ls | grep .txt but if my folder content is: a.txt btxt c.c it will select a.txt and btxt and I only want files that end with .txt. I tried various combinations of regexp but with no result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find may be better than in this case since it is designed for handling file names:

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -name '*.txt' | wc -l
```

Buf if you are very cautious about possibly strange file names:

```
find . -maxdepth 0 -name '*.txt' -exec echo 1 \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

For Grep, using the character '.' means: "any character"... so you'll need to escape the dot:

```
ls | grep -e "\.txt"
```

**edit** in fact the -e option is not even  necessary. this will do the trick:

```
ls | grep "\.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is number of files with extension '.txt' in current directory only, then this will also help.

```
ls -l *.txt | wc -l
```